# How to resolve "error: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists)"?

Tags: git

I am currently on branch `branch-123`.

**=>** **On doing** `git status`, **I am getting the following**:

On branch `branch-123` 
Your branch and `'origin/branch-123'` have diverged, 
and have 9 and 27 different commits each, respectively. 
(use `"git pull"` to merge the remote branch into yours)

All conflicts fixed but you are still merging. 
(use `"git commit"` to conclude merge)

Changes not staged for commit: 
(use "git add ..." to update what will be committed) 
(use "git restore ..." to discard changes in working directory) 
modified:   qwerty.php 
modified:   qwertyConfig.xml

Untracked files: 
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed) 
.qwerty.conf 
files/diagrams/

**=>** **On doing** `git pull`, **I am getting the following:**

error: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists). 
hint: Please, commit your changes before merging. 
fatal: Exiting because of unfinished merge.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to do in order to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is although you have fixed your merge conflicts, you have not committed them. Just commit them and then pull.

```bash
git add .
git commit -m "your message"
git pull
```